# How can I get feh image viewer to view Windows PC networked files?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi and use the feh image viewer https://feh.finalrewind.org/

This works great when my photos are on USB.

I would now like to access my photos via LAN instead from a Windows PC.

I can view my Windows PC folders in vncviewer via:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/Pictures /media/windowspc \-osec=ntlmv2,username=a,password=a
```

I am able to see them all in the File Manager GUI under media/windowspc

I then load feh via:

```
feh -qrYzFD15 --fill /media/windowspc
```

But I get the error:

```
feh: No loadable images specified.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? The same command but to a USB plugged into the pi works fine:

```
feh -qrYzFD15 --fill /media/myusb
```

Comment: Are you able to run other commands, like `file` or `magick identify`, on the mounted share? What happens when you run `feh` on a _specific_ image file with its full path?

Comment: file /media/windowspc/blah/blah.jpg correctly shows data about the image, so does running 'identify'. feh on the same directory and/or file still says 'No loadable images specified'

Comment: I've fixed it! I tried doing feh -l and got an error, after some Googling I found I needed to add 'noserverino' to my mount command and then it all worked.

Comment: @user370 Please post your fix as an answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember if this still works, when I updated the Raspberry Pi OS to a newer major version I had issues but maybe with something else.

sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/Pictures /media/windowspc -osec=ntlmv2,noserverino,username=a,password=a

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).